# c++ compile error

Tags: c++, class, compilation

I have this class for double linked lists:

```
template <typename T>
class Akeraios
{
    struct node
    {
        T data;

        node* prev;

        node* next;

        node(T t, node* p, node* n) : data(t), prev(p), next(n) {}

    };

    node* head;

    node* tail;

public:

    Akeraios() : head( NULL ), tail ( NULL ) {}

    template<int N>

    Akeraios( T (&arr) [N]) : head( NULL ), tail ( NULL )  //meta apo : simainei einai initializer list--arxikopoiisi listas
    {
        for( int i(0); i != N; ++i)

            push_back(arr[i]);

    }

    bool empty() const { return ( !head || !tail ); }
    operator bool() const { return !empty(); } 
    void push_back(T);
    void push_front(T);
    T pop_back();
    T pop_front();

    ~Akeraios()
    {
        while(head)
        {
            node* temp(head);
            head=head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
};
```

and somewhere in main

```
  int arr[num1len];

   int i=1;

     Akeraios <int> dlist ( arr );//error line!!

   for(i=1;i<=num1len;i++){

   double digit;

   int div=10;

   int j;

   for(j=1;j<=i;j++)div=div*div;


   digit=number1/div; 

   int dig=(int) digit;
```

the error in error line is:

> no matching function for call to `Akeraios::Akeraios(int[((unsigned int)((int)num1len))])'
>
> candidates are: Akeraios::Akeraios(const Akeraios&)
>
> note Akeraios::Akeraios() [with T = int]

Comment: num1len is integer-the length of digits of a long number and i want my array to store each digit seperate

Comment: @user501986: Is it a constant or a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is perfectly valid and compliant as-is. The only way I can see it messing up is if you had a compiler extension for VLAs and attempted to call the constructor with a variable-length array, which would almost certainly fail. Otherwise, it is perfectly legitimate. Visual Studio accepts without quarrel.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Akeraios <int>* dlist = new Akeraios( arr );
```

your compiler thinks you're calling a function doing it the way you do it.

you could also use the implicit constructor

```
Akeraios<int> dlist = arr;
```

(not very nice this is)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saying that `num1len` is a variable:

Templates are evaluated at compile-time. When you say `arr[num1len]`, you're specifying an array with a variable length (is this C99 or something?). The template expects an array with a size that can be evaluated at compile time (you're saying `template<int N>Akeraios( T (&arr) [N])`, so there's no way the compiler can match that up.

Just imagine you had a specialization for N=5 or N=10. How would the compiler be able to find the right specialization when compiling the code if the size of the array is not known at that point?